# Concrete form of all finite order automorphisms of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, automorphism-group

A general automorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is given by $x \mapsto \gamma x \gamma^{-1}$ where $x \in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ is written as a $2\times 2$ matrix and $\gamma \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ which is to say that,
$$\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb C$ and $ad-bc = 1.$ I am interested to know the conditions on $a,b,c,d$ such that $\gamma$ is an automorphism of finite order $N$. For it to be finite order this would imply,
$$\gamma^N x (\gamma^{-1})^N = x$$

in addition to the existing condition $ad-bc=1$. I'm not sure how to go beyond this to get a concrete form of $\gamma$.

Comment: Maybe try applying it to some concrete easy matrices (for example ones having all zeros except one 1) and see what you can conclude.

Comment: Up to conjugation, a finite-order element of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ must be of the form $\operatorname{diag}(\zeta_1, \zeta_2)$, where $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are inverse (hence conjugate!) roots of unity.  In turn, any such matrix is conjugate to a (real) rotation through some angle $2\pi/m$ with $m$ a positive integer (the order).  Is this the kind of answer you wanted?

Comment: @LSpice Hi, thanks for your comment. I would like a concrete form of a general finite order automorphism, rather than up to conjugation as my application is not agnostic to conjugation.

Comment: I guess what I mean is:  what's a concrete form?  You can expand out $\frac1{\alpha\delta - \beta\gamma}\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi/m) & \sin(2\pi/m) \\ -\sin(2\pi/m) & \cos(2\pi/m) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \delta & -\beta \\ -\gamma & \alpha \end{pmatrix}$ and have an over-parameterised form; or you could check that, in addition to $a d - b c = 1$, you have that $a + d = 2\cos(2\pi/m)$ for some $m$.  I think it doesn't get much more concrete.